# JavaScript: create MIME message

Tags: javascript, message, mime

I have user interface to send message. User enters a subject, message body, emails to send, attaches some files. After submit I need to send message as MIME message, like this:

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="XXXXboundary text"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain

this is the body text

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="test.txt"

this is the attachment text

--XXXXboundary text--
```

How can I gather user entered information as MIME message? I searched to build MIME message on client side with JavaScript but no success. If attachments exist, I need to convert them base64 string, then send within MIME message. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you compose a mime message on client side, how are you going to send it with javascript?

Comment: @claustrofob Server waits MIME message, web client and mobile (iOS,..) clients send as MIME message. So as web client I should send as MIME message. I hope I can send it as string (text/plain) by ajax.

Comment: Actually it is possible to combine a mime message with javascript. You can find implementation of base64 encode function, you can read file contents with File API. But it will work only in modern browsers (and IE from v10). And it is definitely a huge overhead for the client. Especially operations with attachments. And you actually try to build an email mime message. Isn't it intended for email server? You cannot send emails right from the browser.

Comment: @bob: mime is the *message format*. But what is your *transport protocol*? Without custom plugins, you can only use HTTP(S) or WS(S).

Comment: @Bergi I use http(s). I've created mime message as text. Then I sent it to server as text/plain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've created a javascript plugin to create MIME message in javascript. https://github.com/ikr0m/mime-js. Create `mail` object with necessary properties and call createMimeMessage function. It returns ready MIME message as javascript string.

```
var mail = {  
    "to": "email1@example.com, email2@example.com",
    "subject": "Today is rainy",
    "fromName": "John Smith",
    "from": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "body": "Sample body text",
    "cids": [],
    "attaches" : []
}
var mimeMessage = createMimeMessage(mail);
console.log(mimeMessage);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look to the world of Node.js modules...  you won't be able to actually send your MIME mail message from the browser client since there is no SMTP support provided. But you can POST the pre-formatted message to your web server via XHR and then have the web server actually send the message.

This looks like it could do what you need:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/mailcomposer

i.e. you can prepare a MIME message as a string

this tool may help in terms of using Node.js modules in the browser:
http://browserify.org/

Comment: looks close to what I am looking for. Will check it out.